# in react native how i can change background color for every view element independent

Tags: styles, react-native

for every view element independent when i press them without effect other views and save pressed state so next time i can find what ipressed still pressed and i can change color of other view when ipress them without lose stat of preview view

the problem is when i press one from two task the other task also change her background color

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
   SafeAreaView, 
   View,
   FlatList, 
   StyleSheet, 
   Text,
   TouchableOpacity, 
} from 'react-native';

 
function App() {

  const [changBack,backgroundColor]=useState('green')

  function changIt() {
    backgroundColor('red');
  }
  
  const DATA1 = 'Task one';
  const DATA2 = 'Task two';

  return (
    <View>

      <TouchableOpacity
       style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor:changBack,
        padding: 20,
       }}  
       onPress={changIt}>
        <View>
          <Text>{DATA1}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
       style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor:changBack,
        padding: 20,
       }}  
       onPress={changIt}>
        <View>
          <Text>{DATA2}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   
    </View>

  );
  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    textAlign:'right',
    justifyContent:'space-evenly',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother I notice you passed `backgroundColor` on `Style` for `<TouchableOpacity>` so definitely it won't work. `backgroundColor` is applicable for `<View>` only but not for TouchableOpcacity.

*Do something like this ~*

```
 <View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:changBack}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeIt}>
            <View>
                <Text>Heyya</Text>
            </View>
        </ToucableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
```

*or this,*

```
    <View> 
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeIt}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:changBack}}>
            <Text>Heyya</Text>
        </View>
    </ToucableOpacity>
   </View>
```